Можно ли разделить заполнение таблицы excel между пользователями, чтобы данные не уходили к другому человеку?
у меня есть тг-бот, в который сейчас я добавляю функцию заполнения таблицы Excel через чат. Таблица заполняется по ходу вноса информации в чат, но на практике я понял, что если пользователи одновременно ее заполняют, информация синхронизируется и не разделяется между клиентами.
Есть ли какой-то вариант разделения синхронизации хотя бы на двух пользователей, к примеру? Может заморозка таблицы в моменте или что-то такое, не знаю, как правильно выразиться...
Заранее спасибо огромное!

Как сделал бы я, если я правильно понял проблему.
Так как использую Redis для FSMContext, то использовал бы его.
Сам redis у меня singleton, то есть 1 экземпляр на всех.
Можно сохранить в redis переменную-флаг вроде can_edit с булевым значением.
Если никто не редактирует таблицу, то переменная True.
Если кто-то начал редактирование, то False.
Ну и прописал бы соответствующие правила для начала/завершения редактирования, и для простоя больше n-секунд/минут
